# Completely stumped on exercise cooncerning the characterisation of Jordan measure - would anyone be willing to give a hint?

Tags: measure-theory

In Terry Tao's notes on measure theory he has the following exercise, I have no idea how to deal with the last statement, I would really appreciate it if someone could give a hint for the final case.

Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $E$ is Jordan Measurable
2. For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists elementary sets $A$ and $B$ satisfying $A \subset E \subset B$ such that $m(B/A) \leq \epsilon$
3. For all $\epsilon >0$ there exists an elementary set $A$ such that $m^{*}(A\Delta E) \leq \epsilon,$ where $m^*(\cdot)$ is the Jordan outer measure.

Here is my attempt so far:

$1. \Rightarrow 2.$

Since $E$ is measureable, we have $m(E) = m^*(E) = m_*(E)$ where $m_*(\cdot)$ is the Jordan inner measure.

By assumption we can find elementary sets $B$ and $A$ where  $A \subset E \subset B$ such that $m(B) - m(E) \leq \epsilon$ and $m(E) - m(A) \leq \epsilon.$

It thus follows that $m(B) - m(A) \leq 2\epsilon.$

Since $A$ and $B$ are elementary we have that $m(B) = m(B/A) + m(A).$ combined with the inequality above this gives $m(B/A) \leq 2\epsilon$

$2. \Rightarrow 1.$

Choose $A \subset E \subset B$ with $m(B/A) \leq \epsilon$ then

$\epsilon \geq m(B/A) = m(B) - m(A) \geq m(B) - m_*(E) \geq m^*(E) - m_*(E) = |m^*(E) - m_*(E)|$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the result follows.

Answer (score 4):

$(2) \implies (3)$:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, and let $A\subset E\subset B$ so that $A$ and $B$ are elementary and $m(B-A)<\varepsilon$.

Since $A\subset E\subset B$ and by monotonicity, we have:

$$m^*(E\triangle B)=m^*(B-E)\le m^*(B-A)<\varepsilon.$$

For the implication $(3)\implies (1)$ we need the following lemma:

If $B$ is Jordan measurable and $E\subset B$ then
$$m^*(B-E)=m(B)-m_*(E).$$

Proof of the lemma:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Let $A$ and $C$ be elementery sets so that $A\subset E$, $B\subset C$, $m_*(E)-m(A)<\varepsilon$, and $m(C)-m^*(B)<\varepsilon$ (we have used the fact that $B$ is bounded). We have:
$$m^*(B-E)\le m^*(C-A)=m(C)-m(A)\le m^*(B)-m_*(E)+2\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have:
$$m^*(B-E)\le m^*(B)-m_*(E)=m(B)-m_*(E).$$

For the reverse inequality, let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Let $A$ and $C$ be elementery sets so that $A\subset B$, $(B-E)\subset C$, $m_*(B)-m(A)<\varepsilon$, and $m(C)-m^*(B-E)<\varepsilon$. Then $(A-C)\subset E$, so we have:
$$m(B)-m_*(E)=m_*(B)-m_*(E)$$ 
$$\le m(A)+\varepsilon-m(A-C)=m(C)+\varepsilon\le m^*(B-E)+2\varepsilon$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have:
$$m(B)-m_*(E)\le m^*(B-E).$$

Now, we are ready to prove that

$(3)\implies (1)$:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, and let $E'$ be an elementery set so that $m^*(E\triangle E')<\varepsilon$. Let $B'$ be an elementary set so that $(E-E')\subset B'$ and $m(B')-m^*(E-E')<\varepsilon$. Since $(E-E')\subset (E\triangle E')$, it follows that $m(B')<2\varepsilon$.

Define $B=B'\cup E'$. Then $B$ is elementary and $E\subset B$. By the lemma, $m^*(B-E)=m(B)-m_*(E)$. Therefore:
$$m^*(E)-m_*(E)\le m(B)-m_*(E)=m^*(B-E)=m^*(E'\cup B'-E)$$
$$=m^*((E'-E)\cup (B'-E))\le m^*(E'-E)+m^*(B'-E)<\varepsilon + m(B')<3\varepsilon,$$
and we are done.

Comment: How did you get that $m(A) + \epsilon -m(A-C) = m(C) + \epsilon$ in the fourth last line of the lemma?

Answer (score 0):

$(2) \implies (3)$ was proven by @YoavBarSinai, but their proof of $(3) \implies (1)$ uses some (as yet) unproven properties in the textbook. Here's an alternative.

$(3) \implies (2)$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $A$ be an elementary set such that $m^*(A \Delta E) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$

Let $B$ be elementary and $B \supset (A \Delta E)$ such that

$$
\begin{align*}
m(B) &\leq m^*(A\Delta E) + \frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

We have
$$
(A \backslash B) \subset (A \cap E) \subset E \subset (A \cup E) \subset (A \cup B) \\
$$

For the first $\subset$
$$
\begin{align*}
A \backslash B
&\subset A \backslash (A \Delta E) \\
&= A \backslash (A \backslash E \cup E \backslash A) \\
&= A \backslash (A \backslash E) \\
&= A \cap E
\end{align*}
$$

For the last $\subset$
$$
\begin{align*}
A \cup B
&\supset A \cup (A \Delta E) \\
&= A \cup (A \backslash E) \cup (E \backslash A) \\
&= A \cup (E \backslash A) \\
&= A \cup E
\end{align*}
$$

Then we have
$$
m(A \backslash B) = m(A) - m(A \cap B) \geq m(A) - m(B) \\
m(A \cup B) \leq m(A) + m(B)
$$

Finally
$$
\begin{align*}
m((A \cup B) \backslash (A \backslash B))
&= m(A \cup B) - m(A \backslash B) \\
&\leq m(A) + m(B) - m(A) + m(B) \\
&\leq \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$